# дана дата в формате 2016-05-11 12:46:21.000000, как его обрезать до 2016-05-11 12:46

Tags: java, android, дата

Дана дата (тип `String`) в формате `2016-05-11 12:46:21.000000`, как его обрезать до `2016-05-11 12:46`?

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
try {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(record.getStartTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Обрезать? Легко:

```
String strDate = "2016-05-11 12:46:21.000000";
String cuted = strDate.substring(0, strDate.lastIndexOf(":"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Ответ @SergeyGornostaev как бы правильный и рабочий, конечно, но он как бы так помягче выразиться - не совсем системный.

Системно надо делать так:

```
String dateTimeString;
SimpleDateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Date date = inputDateFormat.parse(dateTimeString);
String outputDateTimeString=outputDateFormat.format(date);
```

По крайней мере у ТС потуги были именно такие, он просто не совсем верно указал формат даты.

Comment: Ну **обрезать** же просили :)

Comment: Да я ж не против :)